# Merge replication with Filestream

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have the scenario where I am using a FILESTREAM enabled table to upload and download files from.

I need the files available in two instances, database A and database B. Files can be uploaded to both A and B and must be synced to the other party. There is no restriction on uniqueness, identical files might be uploaded to the databases. Note the table to be replicated is used only for the files and nothing else.

How reliable is a Merge replication in this case? Some of the files can be up to 2GB in size. Is the replication revertible, i.e. if it fails midway while streaming the files to the other database will all the changes, caused by the replication, be rolled back?